# Positioning numbers in the matrix

Tags: matrix, vector, indexing

How can I get the position of an element of the matrix as an integer?

In this case, access to information on any arbitrary cell can be arranged on the primary key: id. If used as a key field int_32, it is possible to position matrix [216 x 216] and get square with sides of 65.5 thousand cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the matrix size, you can enumerate all cells using, say, `(rowNumber - 1) * columns + columnNumber`, where `columns` is the number of columns in the matrix.

To get the `rowNumber` and `columnNumber` use this:

```
rowNumber = ((id - 1) DIV columns) + 1
columnNumber = ((id - 1) MOD columns) + 1
```

, where `DIV` and `MOD` are integer division and modulo operators, respectively.

Comment: Do you think, Is there a performance dependence on the number of columns?

Comment: @newpdv: for a single invocation of the formula, no. Of course the more columns, the more times will the formula have to be calculated. Anyway, the calculation overhead is negligible compared to the database storage overhead.